# branch not available for merge request in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have a private repo inside GitLab CE hosted on GitLab.com

It states as 4 branches but I actually have 5.

One of the branches is **not** registering properly. The one that's not cannot be merged.

The branch in question has this as the name `hotfix/32-nativix-workwith-only-12142`

My repo is a private repo hence I cannot disclose the repo name.

Please advise.

Comment: Did you correctly set upstream tracking for the branch that didn't register on https://GitLab.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by merging the branches locally and then pushing both the source and destination branches again to the `origin` repo in gitlab remote.

Then, the issue is resolved.

Not sure why.